# Why does not pyqt recognize background colour of Qt Designer css Style Sheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, qt-designer, qtstylesheets

1. I set the background properties in `Qt Designer` with the Style Sheet, e.g. green:

[image]

Apparently it works.

2. I translate the ui-file to pyqt with pyuic4 and get:

---

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        Dialog.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QDialog{background-color: green;}"))
```

3. I write the code in `python` to show the green window, but it doesn’t work.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from background_green import *

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Window()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Although I follow the same process with other `Widgets` trouble-free, I cannot change the colour of my main window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is generated because when you use `QDesigner` you implemented a `QDialog`, so your widget should be of that type.

Change `QWidget` to `QDialog`.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        Dialog.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("QDialog{background-color: green;}")

class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Window()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]